# Valence enrollments in orgUnit with incorrect roleId parameter

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm using /enrollments/orgUnits/{orgUnitid}/users/?roleid=XXX

Works correctly with numeric roleId (both existing and not existing).

When **roleId is not numeric** (eg "Instructor") the call **doesn't throw an error** and **returns all enrollments** in the OU.

Answer (score 0):

That clearly sounds like a defect; I would encourage you to contact [D2L's support desk](http://helpdesk.desire2learn.com) and report it as such (so that you can provide details of your back-end service, like version and service-pack level).